# Can't disable Telerik dropdown list with JQuery

Tags: jquery, telerik, radcombobox

I'm trying to use JQuery to enable a Telerik RadComboBox based on the selection of another Telerik RadComboBox.

Use case: User comes to page, ddlRequired is enabled, ddlListItems is disabled. If user selects "Required" then I want ddlListItems to then be enabled. Conversely, if "Optional" is selected, I want to disable ddlListItems.

```
                <telerik:RadComboBox ID="ddlRequired" runat="server" Width="80px" ShowDropDownOnTextboxClick="true" EnableEmbeddedSkins="false" Skin="Classic"  OnClientSelectedIndexChanged="OnSelectedIndexChanged">
                    <Items>
                        <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Text="Required" Value="1" />
                        <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Text="Optional" Value="0" />
                    </Items>
                </telerik:RadComboBox>

                <telerik:RadComboBox ID="ddlListItems" runat="server" Width="200px" ShowDropDownOnTextboxClick="true" EnableEmbeddedSkins="false" Skin="Classic" Enabled="false">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtBoxQ1" runat="server" Width="160"/>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <Items>
                        <telerik:RadComboBoxItem />
                        <telerik:RadComboBoxItem />
                    </Items>
                </telerik:RadComboBox>
```

Here's where I've left off after trying several approaches. I realize it's not complete.

```
function OnSelectedIndexChanged()
{
    var ddl = $find("<%=ddlListItemsQ1.ClientID%>");
    ddl.set_enabled(false);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

While this isn't really jQuery, more just plain old regular JavaScript, using the [client-side API](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/combobox-client-side-basics.html) of the RadComboBox, specifically the article on the [RadComboBoxItem](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/combobox-client-side-radcombobox.html) (for the enable function) and the [OnClientSelectedIndexChanged](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/combobox-onclientselectedindexchanged.html) article (for details on the eventArgs) I created the following quick little snippet:

```
    function OnSelectedIndexChanged(sender, eventArgs) {
        var selectedItem = eventArgs.get_item();
        if (selectedItem.get_text() === "Required") {
            var ddlListItemsClient = $find('<%= ddlListItems.ClientID %>');
            ddlListItemsClient.enable();
        }
    }
```

I just tested it with the ASPX code you provided and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
disableChildElements( document.getElementById(<%=dropdown_Id.ClientId%>"))

function disableChildElements(objId)
{
    var theObject = document.getElementById(objId);
    var level = 0;
    TraverseDOM(theObject, level, disableElement);
}

function TraverseDOM(obj, lvl, actionFunc)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < obj.childNodes.length; i++)
    {
        var childObj = obj.childNodes[i];
        if (childObj.tagName)
        {
            actionFunc(childObj);
        }
        TraverseDOM(childObj, lvl + 1, actionFunc);
    }
}

function disableElement(obj)
{
    obj.disabled = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't work!

```
$('#ddlListItems').attr('Enabled', 'false');
```

This works!

```
    @(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m.RoleId)
        .Name("RoleId")

    ...

    <script type="text/javascript">
      var ddlist = $("#RoleId").data("kendoDropDownList")
      ddlist.enable(false);

   ...
```

Answer (score -1):

Bit of a stab at it, I know nothing about telerik and I'm useless with ASP/C#, but this *may* work :)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#ddlRequired telerik:RadComboBoxItem').change(function()
    {
        if ($(this).val()) == true)
            $('#ddlListItems').attr('Enabled', 'true');
        else
            $('#ddlListItems').attr('Enabled', 'false');
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Hello,

The RadComboBox has a jQuery object created on the client-side. In order to disable it, you need to call the disable() function. To enable it, you call the enable() function.

Like so:

```
    var combo = $find("<%=RadComboBox1.ClientID%>");
    combo.disable();
```

Or:

```
    $(".rcbInput").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

I hope that helps.